# Google Sheets Conditional Formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

Google Sheets formula for outputting `PASS` or `FAIL` in one cell based on the color (green or red) of another cell?

Comment: for further assistance, you will need to edit your question and add additional information: **1.** conditional formatting formula/rule for green/red **2.** which cell turns green/red **3.** in which cell you need pass/fail to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

if you have a cell (A1) that has conditional formatting set in a way that it will turn red or green and then you have another cell (B1) where you want to display `pass` or `fail` based on red/green cell... use that conditional formatting from a first cell (A1) directly as a criterion for your second cell (B1) in a way where you will use `IF` formula like:

`=if(conditional formatting of cell A1 = green, display "pass", otherwise display "fail")`

---

[image]